# jQuery shows mask, but not popup <div>

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, popup

here is a link to my example: http://jsfiddle.net/fhuNd/6/

When I click on my link, the jQuery fires, but the popup div does not show. Only the appended #mask.

```or-tag-here
   <div id="login-box" class="login-popup"></div>
```

I'm trying to get the login-popup to show. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your issue correctly, you need to change:

```
$(loginBox).fadeIn(300);
```

to:

```
$(".login-popup").fadeIn(300);
```

The problem was that `loginBox = $(this).attr('href');` but since that element's `href="#"`, `.login-popup` wouldn't show up.